# What is the correct random algorithm to use here?

Tags: java, security, random, bouncycastle, jce

If I use `MD5WithRSAEncryption` as a signature algorithm what is the corresponding random algorithm?
I tried `MD5PRNG` but I got:

> java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: SecureRandom MD5PRNG
>   implementation not found

What is the proper random algorithm to be used here to initialize a  `KeyPairGenerator`?
Like `SHA1PRNG` when we use `SHA256WithRSAEncryption`

I mean: `SHA256WithRSAEncryption` is a `key pair algorithm`, while `SHA1PRNG` is a `random generator` to be used by the keypair algorithm. E.g. `keyPairGenerator.initialize(keySize, secureRandom);`
(where `keyPairGenerator` is of class `KeyPairGenerator`)
Are they somehow depend on proper pairing?I.e. can I use MD5WithRSAEncryption with SHA1PRNG?

Comment: Yes. `SHA256WithRSAEncryption` is a key pair algorithm, while `SHA1PRNG` is a random generator to be used by the keypair algorithm. Are they somehow depend on proper pairing?I.e. can I use `MD5WithRSAEncryption` with `SHA1PRNG`?

Answer (score 3):

The hash algorithm, if any, underlying the deterministic random bit generator (DRBG) doesn't matter.

The output of a DRBG is statistically random; if your were able to determine anything about the source of the bits by examining the output, it wouldn't be suitable for cryptographic use.

By the way, the RSA signature algorithm uses a RNG when using the RSA-PSS scheme. Older RSA signatures are deterministic (and this is a weakness).

What *does* matter is the effective strength of an algorithm. For example, you wouldn't want to use SHA-1 with a 3072-bit RSA signature key; the hash not as strong as the encryption algorithm using that key. DRBGs can be [classified by their strength](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-90A/SP800-90A.pdf) as well. The security strength of a DRBG indicates how much computation is needed predict its output without being given its internal state.

The security strength of a good hash-based DRBG is the same as that of the underlying hash function. To find this out, look at [NIST SP 800‑57 Part 1, Table 3.](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-57/sp800-57_part1_rev3_general.pdf) For strong security, 112 bits is the minimum, with 128 bits or more being encouraged. That means using a DRBG based on SHA-224 or SHA-256, with a 2048- or 3072-bit RSA key, respectively.

Comment: So if I use `MD5WithRSAEncryption` keypair generator there is no reason not to use `SHA1PRNG`?

Comment: The fact that it's SHA-1 is just fine. I haven't seen any analysis, but I would guess it gives 80 bits of security and would be a good match for a 1024-bit RSA key. However, I would strongly suggest abandoning MD5 for any purpose, because the algorithm is broken.

Comment: @jim But, in short, no, there is no reason not to use SHA1PRNG.

Answer (score 2):

The only issue with SHA1PRNG is that the keyspace is for some reason limited to 20 bytes.  This is totally unnecessary since the hash can be performed on a virtually unlimited amount of text.  It is not clear to me why there is a limit on the keysize for this generator.  The good news it is easy to copy the source code and remove that limitation. The bad news is that it is then not compatible with the standard implementation.